# Insert into DB using remote server

Tags: python, server

I am using a search API to fetch some results. These results are inserted into the database. The only issue is it takes too much time. What I want to do is get my script running, even when I close my laptop it should be running and inserting records into the remote database. Does running the script on the server like this helps:

python myscript.py &

Comment: Typically, when you close your laptop, the operating system gets suspended and nothing is running.  If you want it to not suspend, that is more of a system configuration issue than a programming issue, and should be asked elsewhere (e.g., on [superuser.com](http://superuser.com/)).

Comment: That is the correct way to start background process on the remote server.  You might also learn about running `screen` on the remote server.  https://www.mattcutts.com/blog/a-quick-tutorial-on-screen/

Comment: What if I want to keep a record of the print statements in the python script to a log file? Is this the command to do it? 
nohup python  myscript.py & > /dev/null 2>&1 &